# how to stop Google crawl /fileadmin

Tags: html, apache, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I use TYPO3 in a site containing some 4 thousand pages. 
In /fileadmin I store html pages that TYPO3 fetches using the "fetchurl" plugin. The folders structure has the same hierarchical structure as the TYPO3 page tree as: fileadmin/folder1/folder2/folder3/file.html which is rendered as www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/file.html
In all cases the tree  corresponds exactly to the navigation structure of the web site.

The html pages contain minimum formatting tags like p, div, img and so on. No css, no heading, no footer. TYPO3 do the rest. 
I protected /fileadmin using robots.txt to avoid indexing by crawlers. Yes, I know crawlers crawl everything irrespective of the robots.txt. (BTW in Apache I have blocked access to many crawlers).

This approach worked ok for 20 years without issues, but today I received an email from Google that reads:

> Top Warnings. ... Some warnings can affect your appearance on Search;
>   **some might be reclassified as errors in the future** (emphasis mine). The following warnings were found on your site: Indexed, though blocked by
>   robots.txt We recommend that you fix these issues when possible to
>   enable the best experience and coverage in Google Search.

The question is what's the best approach to overcome this problem?

- -Replace the html extension by something else and using FilesMatch restriction?
- -Use folder permission to block access from outside?
- -Move /fileadmin outside public_html? (For years I have thought to move many folders outside public_html)
- -Use 'noindex' tag? (Does it work in an filename.html without !DOCTYPE declaration and no head tag?)
- Any other idea?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you'd want to move the files outside the document root (public_html). I don't know the `fetchurl` extension, but from the description you need a URL to access the files. So this might not be an option without replacing this extension.

If moving the files outside the document root isn't an option, I'd restrict access by IP address. You can do this by adding a `.htaccess` file (assuming they .htaccess support isn't disabled on your server) to fileadmin with the following content:

```
<RequireAny>
  Require local
</RequireAny>
```

Or if using Apache <2.4:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from ::1
```

Comment: That seems to be an immediate solution, providing Google do not dislike it. However I need to move some scripts from /fileadmin to another place.